# How can I fix my fixed navbar scrolling problem?

Tags: wordpress, position, overflow, fixed

I am trying to emulate an "Instagram" style menu for a website for its mobile version. Everything is fine but the problem is that I have a little scrolling issue with the x and y axis in which there are a few pixels more than intended.

I would like to make it 100% fixed so no scrolling is triggered.

I would paste the code but as I am working with a commercial Wordpress theme I find it over-complicated.

The website url is:

https://www.galaventura.com

Thank you very much

Actualization:
I provide two screenshots to support my question. In the first one there is the current state of the navbar. In the second one, the result I seek. Don't pay attention to the unaligned icons. A third image is provided to synthesize my exposure and might make the issue clearer.
[image: Screenshot 1-Current state of the navbar]

[image: Screenshot 2-Desired result]

[image: Graphic explanation]

Comment: Can you supply a screenshot of the problem and of how you'd like the final solution to look?

Comment: @Tokant thank you, I provided graphic documentation to support my question.

Comment: Hi David. In your screenshot only 3 menu items are visible but you have a 4th called INICIO. Do you want to show that one as well, i.e. all 4 list items visible on one row without scrolling?

Comment: @Tokant that's right. Although I am not sure if that is the source of my problem.

Comment: It is not the source of your problem but a further clarifies what is wrong (your green box should extend to the left as well).

Answer (score 0):

The texts in the anchor links (INICIO, NOSOTROS, etc.) breaks the layout. So set font-size to something small, for example 10px:

```
.ast-header-break-point .main-navigation li {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: setting the font-size to a small number (have tried 1px) has fixed the issue of the alignment of the icons. Now all of them are at their place. Thank you. But the scrolling problem persists.

Comment: In what browser are you experiencing the scroll?

Comment: only in Google Chrome. Why would that be?